# Running Android app on device using gradle

Tags: android, gradle, adb

I am trying to build `Android` app using `Gradle` and run it on a device automatically. I use Eclipse Kepler. This is my command:

```
~/Documents/Multiverse: $ gradle appStart
```

I am getting this error:

```
:appStart
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.alwawee.main/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.alwawee.main/com.alwawee.main.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

I can't understand how to solve this.

My `Gradle.build` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/androidannotations-api-3.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-lang3-3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/flurryAnalytics_3.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1"
}

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}

/*android {
      lintOptions {
          abortOnError false
      }
}*/

task appStart(type: Exec, dependsOn: ':installDebug') {
    // linux 
    commandLine 'adb', 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.alwawee.main/com.alwawee.main.MainActivity'

    // windows
    // commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'adb', 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.alwawee.main/com.alwawee.main.MainActivity'      
}
```

This is my src structure in Eclipse: 
[image]

This is my Manifest file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.alwawee.multiverse"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.0.8" >

    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />


    <application android:name="com.alwawee.application.AppApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/android:Theme.Holo.Light" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.alwawee.main.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.alwawee.webView.WebViewActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/web_activity_name">
            <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
              <action android:name="com.example.intentdemo.LAUNCH" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
              <data android:scheme="http" />
           </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.alwawee.entityList.MVEntityListActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:parentActivityName="com.alwawee.main.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.alwawee.entitylist.EntityListActivity" />
        </activity>

    </application>



</manifest>
```

Probably, the problem is that I use custom `Application`.

Comment: post your AndroidManifest

Comment: post your *complete* manifest, particularly the root `<manifest>` element.

Comment: done, posted complete manifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command line is wrong. Your package name is `com.alwawee.multiverse`. Change:

```
commandLine 'adb', 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.alwawee.main/com.alwawee.main.MainActivity'
```

to:

```
commandLine 'adb', 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.alwawee.multiverse/com.alwawee.main.MainActivity'
```

Comment: I thought that the package name is the package name for MainActivity class. So, I was wrong. It's a name for a whole app's package name.

Comment: there is no need for local shell to parse the `adb shell` command: `commandLine 'adb', 'shell', 'am start -n com.alwawee.multiverse/.MainActivity'`